# Where's the right place to post feature requests?

Tags: pantheon-files

I couldn't find a repository. Sorry. I felt like I was really close [here](https://elementary.io/open-source), but no.

Comment: GitHub might be the right place. It depends on the feature and what component of the OS it's related too.

Answer (score 3):

elementary is now [hosted on GitHub](https://github.com/elementary). So just go to the right repository and open an issue. This is the [repository for pantheon-files](https://github.com/elementary/files)

This is an example of a feature request I made for AppCenter.
https://github.com/elementary/appcenter/issues/411